# Getting the Date and numeric weekday in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, dayofweek, weekday

i'm developing an application in PHP and I need to use dates and the numeric representation of weekdays.

I've tried the following:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$number = date('N', strtotime($today));
echo "Today: " . $today . " weekday: " . $number . "<br>";
$today = strtotime($today);
$tomorrow = strtotime($today);
$tomorrow = strtotime("+1 day", $today);
$number2 = date('N', strtotime($tomorrow));
echo "Tomorrow: " . date('Y-m-d', $tomorrow) . " weekday: " . $number2 . "<br>";
```

#### Output

```
Today: 2016-11-11 weekday: 5
Tomorrow: 2016-11-12 weekday: 4
```

This isn't right because the weekday of tomorrow should be 6 instead of 4.

can someone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have little error in the code, here`s the working one:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$number = date('N', strtotime($today));
echo "Today: " . $today . " weekday: " . $number . "<br>";

$today = strtotime($today);
$tomorrow = strtotime($today);
$tomorrow = strtotime("+1 day", $today);
$number2 = date('N', $tomorrow);
echo "Tomorrow: " . date('Y-m-d', $tomorrow) . " weekday: " . $number2 . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 11):

Using `DateTime` would provide a simple solution

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
echo 'Today: '.$date->format( 'Y-m-d' ) .' weekday '. $date->format( 'N' )."\n";
$date->modify( '+1 days' );
echo 'Tomorrow: '.$date->format( 'Y-m-d' ) .' weekday '. $date->format( 'N' )."\n";
```

Output

```
Today: 2016-11-11 weekday 5
Tomorrow: 2016-11-12 weekday 6
```

However the day numbers are slightly different, the N respresents the weekday number and as you can see Friday (Today) is shown as 5.  With that Monday would be 1 and Sunday would be 7.

If you look at the example below you should get the same result

```
echo date( 'N' );
```

Output

```
5
```

Date Formatting - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I think this is the best answer because it's showing how to use `DateTime` before `date`, which is very important for the PHP community evolution.

Answer (score 4):

DateTime is the Object Oriented method of working with dates in PHP. I find it to be working much more fluently. That aside, it looks alot better.

```
// Create a new instance
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format('N');

// Next day
$now->modify('+1 day');
echo $now->format('N');
```

#### Resources

- [DateTime manual - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score -1):

You almost have it right but not quite. Why are you using `strtotime` on `$number2`? Change it to `$number2 = date('N', $tomorrow);` and it will work.