# How to echo the current day from an array of days?

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php  
    $days = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday" ,"Friday" ,"Saturday" ,"Sunday"); 

    foreach ($days as $value) {
      echo "
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>$value</button>";
    }
    ?> 
    <h1 class="normal" style="text-align: center;color:black ">Today is <?php echo "$value"; ?></h1> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move the h1 inside the loop...? You didn't explain what the problem is exactly, but certainly $value will only output its last state, if you use it after the loop ends. Or did you actually want the h1 to tell you _today's_ date (as its text suggests) rather than listing all the days in the array? Your post is unclear. If you want today's date, your array is not relevant to that - PHP can just tell you directly.

Comment: @ADyson then they would get "Today is Monday", "Today is Tuesday", etc., seven h1 in total - I don't think that's what they want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the Date and numeric weekday in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543900/getting-the-date-and-numeric-weekday-in-php)

Comment: @CBroe was just updating the comment with that exact thought

Comment: echo date('l');

Comment: @ADyson i want the h1 to echo only the current day not dates, so lets say today is Monday, I want the h1 to be "Today is Monday" - if today is Tuesday then the output should be "Today is Tuesday"

Comment: Well you don't need an array of days for that (as your title appears to imply). Just see the answer below, it's very simple. It's unclear why you tried to use `$value` in the h1, or what you thought it would do?

Comment: @ADyson I guess you're right but what if I want the today's button to be different - lets say the buttons are all blue and I want today's button to be green - you need the array then correct? I think that's more of my question

Comment: Ah ok. I think Chinkesh's answer below should show you a way to do that. But that totally wasn't what you asked originally...next time, read your post through to ensure it fully clarifies what you mean. Generally, if you just have a rather broad title and a code dump, it means you haven't explained enough. See [ask] for more guidance. The number of downvotes this question has received probably reflects that lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the current day of the week, php provides a function called `date()`

Which the documentation can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

As for your code, You can mention all of the days, however the system would not know the day simply from an array. It would need to access the current time. You can do this by modifying your code as such.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php  
    $days = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday" ,"Friday" ,"Saturday" ,"Sunday"); 

    foreach ($days as $value) {
      echo "
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>$value</button>";
    }
    ?> 
    <h1 class="normal" style="text-align: center;color:black ">Today is <?php echo date('l'); ?></h1> 

    </body>
</html>
```

However since you seem to be using a button, some might believe that you're expecting to display the value clicked.

Please update your question if that is the case. Otherwise this code will always display the current day of the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think This Should be Your Solution if you make days arrays as indexed array as below

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <?php  
    $today = "";
    $days = array(
        1 => "Monday",
        2 => "Tuesday",
        3 =>  "Wednesday",
        4 => "Thursday",
        5 => "Friday",
        6 => "Saturday",
        7 => "Sunday"
    ); 

    foreach ($days as $key=>$value) {
        if(date('N')==$key){
            $today = $value;
            echo "<button type='button' style='background: red'>$value</button>";
        }else{
            echo "<button type='button'>$value</button>";
        }
    }
    ?> 
    <h1 class="normal" style="text-align: center;color:black ">Today is <?php echo "$today"; ?></h1> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Arrays start at 0 in php